# Python IDLE Not Working

Tags: python, python-idle, python-3.2

I've recently been installing, uninstalling, and reinstalling different versions of Python and Pygame to get both working, as well as IDLE. The first issue I had was with Python's IDLE not working, which happened after uninstalling a 3.4~ version of Python for a 3.2 version to be able to use the Pygame module.

For a while, things worked fine, but then I uninstalled 3.2 of both , swapping to 3.1.3 to try using a different IDE. After realizing that pygame didn't work properly in other IDE's, I switched back to 3.2 and found that IDLE no longer worked. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times to no avail.

I tried to delete registry keys related to python to do a complete reinstall, but that doesn't seem to have done anything either.

By not working, I mean that IDLE simply doesn't open  when prompted, when executing it from `C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib`, and also when right clicking on a script and selecting "Edit with IDLE" Running it from the command line, it gives the following error:

```
`C:\>Python32\python.exe C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\idle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\idle.py", line 11, in <module>
    idlelib.PyShell.main()
File "C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1386, in main
    flist.new()
File "C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\FileList.py", line 49, in new
    return self.EditorWindow(self, filename)
File "C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 107, in __init__
    EditorWindow.__init__(self, *args)
File "C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\EditorWindow.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.apply_bindings()
File "C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\EditorWindow.py", line 977, in apply_bindings
    text.event_add(event, *keylist)
File "C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\MultiCall.py", line 359, in event_add
    widget.event_add(self, virtual, seq)
File "C:\Python32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1353, in event_add
    self.tk.call(args)
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Shift"`
```

Comment: Open the Command Prompt (search in start menu for it). Try to run IDLE with Python by entering: `C:\Python32\python.exe C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib\idle.py`. Does it print any errors?

Comment: It posts the following:
http://postimg.org/image/myji2f1nr/

Comment: It would be far better if you copy-pasted the text rather than posting an image. I put it in the body, but nobody can search for it.  Also, if for PyGame issue is separate, post that as another question.

Comment: Alright, done and noted.

Comment: You can use any version of Python 3 you want - I'd suggest using 3.4. Then, download a PyGame installer from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) for your version of Python.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I was able to update to 3.4 on Python and Pygame with everything working, which IS better than 3.2... Unfortunately, the IDLE still doesn't work.

Comment: Unlike many Linux distributions, Windows has no 'system Python'.  There is no need to delete one version of Python to install another.  The only problem with installing multiple versions of Python on windows is which is the default for 'python' at the command line and rt. click 'Edit with Idle'.  When you install, there is a box [x] make this the default version.  I believe you can change this (without directly editing the registry) from the Control Panel / Programs and Features (Win 7), select version, select Change.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here's the solution that worked for me:

"Try deleting the contents of the .idlerc folder in your profile. To open the folder just type  and enter %USERPROFILE%.idlerc."

Link to the other question in full: https://serverfault.com/questions/288457/python-idle-just-doesnt-start-up

Comment: I have no idea how a user config file (in particular config_keys.cfg) in .idlerc got messed up, but the solution of deleting the directory (or just its contents) is consistent with  the traceback above.  Working on improving Idle's response to config errors is near the top of my priority list.

Answer (score 1):

Try repairing the program. Got to your Control Panel>>Change or remove programs>>Pythonxx. But it will give you an option to repair Python. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by 
Uninstalling the previous version and reinstalled the new version then it worked